# Shipping and Billing Address normalization

Tags: normalization

I am currently normalizing the shipping and billing addresses on our software. So basically we have some areas where when orders are made, our system will check if the billing and shipping addresses match or not. If not then it is automatically adds to the fraud queues. The system works fine but the problem arises when users enters their address differently on shipping and billing... for example:

`Shipping Address = "1209 9th Avenue Circle"`

`Billing Address = "1209 9th Ave. Circle"`

So I used regular expression to replace Avenue to Ave on the addresses using full words so it is working in all of my test cases. I have done the similar things to following words.

```
'avenue' : 'ave',
'street' : 'st',
'boulevard': 'blvd',
'parkway': 'pkwy',
'highway': 'hwy',
'drive': 'dr',
'place': 'pl',
'expressway': 'expy',
'heights': 'hts',
'junction' : 'jct',
'center': 'ctr',
'circle' : 'cir',
'cove' : 'cv',
'lane' : 'ln',
'road' : 'rd',
'court' : 'ct',
'square' : 'sq',
'loop' : 'lp'
```

So I was wondering if I am missing any of the key words that are used in addresses or if someone could direct me to a link where I can find the list of Abbreviated words used in US addresses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful using regular expressions to normalize or validate street addresses, because street addresses are not regular. I am a developer at SmartyStreets, which is an address validation/cleansing company, and I've seen some crazy addresses that were something like '1234 Street Rd, Street, MD'. A regex would mangle that kind of address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm seems to have a pretty extensive list and is the official US Postal Services website

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks man. if you were here I would have bought you a mountain dew ;)